# Setting variables in UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, subclass

I have a UITableViewCell subclass I need to have two UIColor variables in. I've declared them in the header but where in the implementation would I set their values for access later?

I need a similar method to `viewDidLoad` so that I can set these when the cell loads. I have tried setting them in `initWithStyle` but its no good as I don't use that to create my cells.

In my view controller I load them in like below:

```
CustomCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

So where would I set these variables? (I want to try and keep them inside the subclass.)

### Edit

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboards with prototypes, registering a class for reuse or registering a nib for reuse?

Comment: can u show me ur `cellForRow` method..

Comment: Added my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method for seeing. I'm using prototypes in a storyboard.

Comment: According to your cellForRowAtIndesPath sample you DO use initWithStile. But if you don't, init should be called always - even if initWithXY or so is called originally.

Comment: But as I mention in the answer below, that method in my subclass is never called. But are you saying, if I just use the standard plain `init` method, that will always be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using storyboards and prototypes, then your cell will have `awakeFromNib` called on it when first created. You can put your code in here.

`initWithStyle:` is not called because your cell is being loaded from a nib. It will be initialised using `initWithCoder:` instead. You could put your code there as well, or in a shared setup method called from there and initWithStyle (if you change the way you use the cells in the future).

Comment: Ahah! That did the trick thanks for clearing this up. Makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

initWithStyle is the designated initializer for UITableViewCell classes so you have to use that method to init a UITableViewCell. Dequeing only works if you have init your cell and there are cells available to dequeue.

You can see your code that you alloc and init if the cell is nil.

Comment: I see what your saying, however the `initWithStyle` method never gets called.

Comment: Are you sure? Set a breakpoint inside that method in your CustomCell

Comment: Also you are not implementing the UITableView dataSource correctly. You should implement - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Well I've changed this as suggested and sadly no difference.

Comment: With storyboards and prototype cells, a cell is always dequeued. The tableView takes care of this for you. See my answer.